# How to pass data to controller discreetly in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to implement user selectable themes using .NET MVC. The themes are stored as css bundles, and I alter the bundle request from a variable I store in the session:

```
@{
    if (Session["Theme"] == null)
    {
        Session["Theme"] = "cerulean";
    }
}
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/" + Session["Theme"] + "/css")
```

Now, the only way I have been able to pass the theme string to the controller in order to modify the Session variable is through route parameters, which are exposed to the user (at least on the first page).

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Default", "Index/default", "Home")</li>
```

I've been trying to come up with a way to pass these parameters to the controller using a form and or hidden field of some sort, but have been unsuccessful thus far. I feel like I'm approaching this from the wrong angle perhaps, is there a something I'm missing or a better way to solve this?

EDIT:

I wasn't exactly clear on how the users chooses a theme. I have a dropdown menu of links similar to the one above. The user clicks on one of the links and I handle the route parameter values into the Session variable. The Session variable is read and chooses which bundle to load depending on the chosen theme.

Comment: A tiny `<form>` with a dropdown `<input>` selector and a submit button with text "Change Theme". As long as the name of the input matches the parameter name in your action it should make it through to the controller action.

Comment: Where are the user theme settings stored, in the first place?  A database? A cookie?

Comment: It currently is in a dropdown of sorts, but since I'm using bootstrap it's a list of anchor elements on the navbar, and I'm having a hard time translating that to a form input element to POST over to the controller. The settings are stored in the Session variable.

Comment: There's lots of questions already about how to make a dropdown list form in MVC. I use bootstrap and technique for making dropdowns is pretty much the same except you might decorate the form with the inline bootstrap classes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+dropdownlist

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `theme` information as a controller parameter if it's already being stored in a session variable?

Comment: I'm not really familiar on the methods to pass data between the server and the client. But I use the controller to modify the Session variable where the theme is stored. I don't modify it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this value in a cookie and implement a global filter that is going to populate your session:

On the client side you can use [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) so your code for setting it will be something like:

```
$.cookie('theme', 'cerulean');
```

*You didn't specify how exactly user chooses a theme but assuming it is a drop-down list or a button you will have to place this code into a corresponding event handler.*

On a server side use [custom action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) to extract theme variable from cookie and populate the session.

You should also have a failover (default theme) in case that cookie wasn't passed.

Another solution would be using custom view engine that supports themes.